# What is causing my argument out of range exception?

Tags: c#, wpf

im trying to test if my list is collecting data from a database but when i try to get a message box to print a postcode from the list it gives me the exeption `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Parameter name: index'`

here are the methods which i have written and am using

```
        private List<string> GetPostcodes(string table)

    {

        connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        connect.Open();

        string selectString = "select postcode from " + table;



        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectString,connect);

       reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())

        {

            postcodes.Add(reader.GetOrdinal("postcode").ToString());

        }

        connect.Close();



        return postcodes;

    }
```

the list `postcodes` is defined earlier in my code like this `List<string> postcodes = new List<string>();`

and here is how im trying to test the collection of the postcodes

```
        private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        string test1 = postcodes[1];

        MessageBox.Show(test1);

    }
```

Comment: This is not [tag:c].

Comment: @SouravGhosh thanks m8

Comment: If you target index 1; `postcodes[1]`, you'll actually targetting the 2nd element. are you aware of that? ( use `postcodes[0]` for the first )

Comment: Side note: use `using` statements to dispose of objects that implement `IDisposable`...

Comment: We tried the first index `postcodes[0]` and that also gave the same error. about the index is out of bounds. is there a problem with the way that the postcodes are being retrived in the `GetPostcodes` method which we cannot see?

Comment: FYI `GetOrdinal` will return the index of the column name and not the actual data from that column.  So, you're filling up your list with the same number over and over again.

Comment: we also just tried `GetString` but that also did not work, we no longer get the error but the `MessageBox.Show()` just now shows an empty message box

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see if you get any records returned. Put a breakpoint in your button Click event & see how many elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that `string test1 = postcodes[1];` is the line causing the issue, clearly index 1 does not exist in the `postcodes` list.

Remember that index 1 refers to the *second* element in C#.  If you only have one postcode, or you meant to refer to the *first* element, you need to use:

```
string test1 = postcodes[0];
```

You could also check to see whether the postcode at index 1 exists:

```
if (postcodes.Count >= 2)
    // postcodes[1] definitely exists
    ...
```